# phpunit composer file not found

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I have this structure of a project:

```
root
    -lib
        -dir
            -file1 (namespace PROJECT\dir\)
            -file2
    -tests
        -dir
            -file1Test
            -file2Test (namespace PROJECT\tests)
    -vendor
```

Composer.json is as follows:

```
 "require-dev":{
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.0.*"
},
"autoload":{
"psr-4":{
    "PROJECT\\": "lib/"
    }
}
```

If I run tests without using classes from lib, everything works well. But (for example) if I have

file1Test.php

```
use PROJECT\dir\file1;

function void testMethod(){
$var = new file1();}
```

I get this:

```
Class PROJECT\dir\file1 not found in full/path/to/file1Test.php
```

Does anyone know where the problem could be?

Comment: What does your PHPUnit bootstrap process look like? Did you `require` the composer autoloader from PHPUnit when tests are run?

Comment: There are a few ways to accomplish that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15711324/541091

Comment: `function void testMethod(){` is not valid PHP, get rid of the `void`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add `phpunit.xml` to your root, with following content.

```
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
</phpunit>
```

This would load all classes loaded by composer.

Comment: After adding this file, I got unfortunately the same error.

Comment: I would try camel case naming. Project\Lib\File1. Your naming is not really standard. See PSR-1 for file naming standard, that is used by composer. PSR-4 is its simpler successor.