# PHPUnit test error, cannot find class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm, autoload

I'm new in PHPUnit and unit-testing, so I was install PHPUnit and phar via composer and everything had been going fine until I was try to start my simple test. I'm using PhpStorm where I can see all classes were autoload, but when I trying to start my test I got an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PharIo\Manifest\Simple' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydocs\
```

I don't understand why he is looking for It in folder upper than PHPUnit is exists ?

I was trying to configure autoload section in composer.json and checking settings in phpunit.xml but nothing works.

**Add:**

I have to reinstall PHPUnit without PharIO, so now I have a little bit of progress, now I have a situation where I can test my class if I make require_once line with a name of the tested class. It looks like:

```
require_once '../src/Simple.php';

class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testAdd() {

        $sum = new Simple();

        $this->assertEquals(5, $sum->add(2, 3));

    }

}
```

So my simple class is:

```
class Simple {

public function add($a, $b) {

    return (int) $a + (int) $b;

}

}
```

But, of course, I want to use namespaces. I try to make some changes based on this question: [Autoloading classes in PHPUnit using Composer and autoload.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710410/autoloading-classes-in-phpunit-using-composer-and-autoload-php) (I was try even use that repo for test, but an error is still exists) but nothing works for me. I was try to edit my autoload section in the composer.json like this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "src/"
    }

},
```

But an error is still exists, another words autoload cannot see It. I was create phpunit.xml and phpunit.dist.xml with a same settings

```
<phpunit
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/3.7/phpunit.xsd"
        backupGlobals="true"
        backupStaticAttributes="false"
        colors="true"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        processIsolation="false"
        stopOnFailure="false"
        syntaxCheck="false"
        bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php">

        <testsuites>
                <testsuite name="The project's test suite">
                        <directory>./tests</directory>
                </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

and I made tests/bootstrap.php too with

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Post screenshots with your config. Other than that: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications

Comment: Do you have a `phpunit.xml.dist` file? If so, can you post it?

Comment: Yes, I already add It to my post

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but maybe you need to do

`composer dump-autoload` for composer to generate the map of classes.

I wasted 30mins trying to understand why PHPUnit was giving me:

`Cannot stub or mock class or interface XXX because it doesn't exists`

Answer (score 2):

Composer's autoload relies on configuration located in the `vendor/autoload.php` file which needs to be loaded at some point in your execution thread. You application already includes this and that's why it works, but the tests use a different entry point so you need to configure it with a file called `phpunit.xml.dist`.

Assuming your file structure is something like:

```
app/
src/
tests/
  bootstrap.php <- create it in your test folder
vendor/
...
composer.json
composer.lock
phpunit.xml.dist <- create it if does not exist
```

You can see the various options [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html), but for a basic config, you can use this.

File `phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/3.7/phpunit.xsd"
    backupGlobals="true"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
</phpunit>
```

File `tests/bootstrap.php`:

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

You should run `phpunit` from the root.

Comment: I try to do every advised step, but autoload still doesn't work. Why we need to create bootstrap.php?! can we add this path right into xml config to the vendor/autoload.php?!

Answer (score 1):

### You should specify the script with autoloading classes.

You can either specify the file with autoloading in [XML-file](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions), as suggested in the other answer, or just by specifying `--bootstrap` [option](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) in your command to run tests:

`phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests`

Comment: When I'm trying this command I'm getting an error: 


`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getSeleniumBro`