# Slim/Http/Environment not found in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, composer-php, slim

I'm developing an API with `Slim/Composer` and I am currently trying to implement some unit testing with `PHPUnit`. I keep running into an error when I run the test via command line:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Slim\Http\Environment' not found
in C:\workspace\client\website\client\api\client-api\src\testclasses\dao\GenreDaoTest.php
on line 15
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.1",
        "slim/php-view": "^2.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.5.1",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "tuupola/slim-jwt-auth": "^2.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": ["classes/dao",
                 "classes/controller",
                 "classes/app",
                 "testclasses/dao"]
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
    }
}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
<?php

use \Slim\Http\Environment as Environment;
use \Slim\Http\Request as Request;
use \Slim\Http\Response as Response;

class GenreDaoTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

   public function testTemp() {
      $this->assertEquals(0, 0);
   }

   public function testGenres() {

      $environment = Environment::mock([
         'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
         'REQUEST_URI' => '/api/v1/genres'
      ]);

      $request = \Slim\Http\Request::createFromEnvironment($environment);
      $response = new Response();

      $this->assertEquals('test', 'test');
   }
}
?>
```

If I comment out the entire 2nd test, leaving the use statements, the first test will pass with no problem. I thought maybe it was something to do with the location of the test file, so I moved it to the classes/app directory where I have other classes with similar imports, and I'm seeing the same results, so I don't *think* it's and issue with where the file lives.

The only 2 things I can think of is that something is happening when I run the test via the command line ($phpunit src/testclasses/dao/GenreDaoTest.php) or something is wrong with my Composer setup.

I'm a Java engineer usually, so I may be missing something simple in the PHP realm, too :)

Anyone have any suggestions? I greatly appreciate it!

(also, I understand that I probably shouldn't be testing API requests/responses in a test for a DAO, I'm in the process of refactoring)

Comment: do you have `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` somewhere?

Comment: Did you run phpunit with `--bootstrap vendor/autoload.php`? That is necessary so the class files could be discovered when needed.

Comment: @Nima that was the issue. It worked when I ran:

phpunit --bootstrap src/vendor/autoload.php src/testclasses/dao/GenreDaoTest.php

It should be noted that this only worked when I used --bootstrap src/vendor/autoload.php BEFORE the test class. It did not work with --bootstrap src/vendor/autoload.php at the end.

Comment: So I'll post an answer explaining the issue :)

Comment: You can also reference the boostrap file in your phpunit.xml. Maybe add that to the answer as well.

Comment: Here is a similar question with detailed answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710410/autoloading-classes-in-phpunit-using-composer-and-autoload-php

Answer (score 0):

When using `phpunit` you can tell it to include `vendor/autoload.php` before running tests. To do so you can change phpunit.xml to include this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
    ...
</phpunit>
```

Or you can pass `--bootstrap vendor/autoload.php` to `phpunit` command when invoking it from command line:

```
phpunit --boostrap vendor/autoload.php <tests directory>
```

Read more in [PHPUnit documentations](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html) under section **Test Execution**.
I also suggest reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710410/autoloading-classes-in-phpunit-using-composer-and-autoload-php) and its answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Slim 4 and had the same problem.

I changed :

```
use \Slim\Http\Request as Request;
```

by

```
use Slim\Psr7\Environment;
```

and works for me !!!

Comment: I did so, and I get `Error: Class 'Slim\Psr7\Environment' not found`
May it depends on installation option? I am using `nyholm/psr7` package ... so, has that a Environment to use? I am guessing, I can not understand